# Trino issue with MySql v5.7 datetime(6) data type

Tags: trino

I have a table in MySQL v5.7 that has a column created_at of datatype datetime(6) and I am querying this table with Trino via superset.

When I run the query "SELECT * FROM subscriptions LIMIT 5" it raise an exception **trino error: Invalid value of epochMicros for precision 0: 1685931465420177**

However if I run the same query without selecting the created_at column it runs fine.

The issue is not there if the same query is executed from other sql client like dbeaver.

Looking for a workaround for this. I am using Trino -v422